# Showing hreflang code in <head></head>

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to generate a code to show hreflang meta attributes in `<head></head>`. For example:

In homepage, it must be showed as

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="http://kemalsunalizle.org" />
```

In a post or page, it must be showed as

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="http://kemalsunalizle.org/{the rest of url}" />
```

What should I do to provide it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the code below:

```
<?php $mylovelyurl = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
<?php if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
echo "<link rel='alternate' hreflang='tr' href='http://kemalsunalizle.org' />";
} else {
echo "<link rel='alternate' hreflang='tr' href='$mylovelyurl' />";
}
?>
<br />
```

You can use it with changing the kemalsunalizle.org with your domain and hreflang tags.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help (comments): https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-meta-tags-vs-googles-hreflang-links

Check comments from zakoops

**Updated:**
If to use builtIn function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url

you can put this into the href and it will return ALWAYS all the path to the current page (notwithstanding it is the ROOT or a page/post/cat).
Or simply: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying it now.

Comment: it only adds one hreflang attribute to all pages and posts :( I need to add the current url as hreflang attribute

Comment: I guess I couldn't still make it. May I ask you to check it? http://kemalsunalizle.org/yesil-yol-izle-720p-turkce-dublaj-full-hd-izle.html